# List object initialization

Tags: c#, list-initialization

I've got a basic conceptual doubt and have been looking for an answer for some time now. I've initialized a list in the following manner :

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };
```

Just this once I missed the () and initialized it in the following manner instead :

```
List<string> list = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
```

No compile time or run time error was thrown. so I want to know if the second method is right? And what is the difference between the two?

Comment: The `()` is optional, there is no difference. If you look at the IL it should be the same.

Comment: You have to use `()` when providing arguments to the constructor, otherwise can omit them when using object initializer.

Comment: I get it now, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Both does the same job, where **()** is optional

In your first example, the compiler knows that you're calling the default constructor

```
  List<string> list = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
```

In the second, you explicitly call the default constructor

```
  List<string> list = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };
```